# subview does not present buttons or imageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

The view that is presented as a subview of another view has the following setup in a .Xib file. 
[image]

Here is how the view is presented when the button to present it is touched.
[image]

Here is the code for how the view is presented.

```
-(void)setUpImageSelectorView{
    ImageSelectorViewViewController *imageSelectorVC = [[ImageSelectorViewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageSelectorViewViewController" bundle:nil];
    imageSelectorVC.delegate = self;
    imageSelectorVC.view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageSelectorVC.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageSelectorVC.imageView.image = img;
    [self.view addSubview:imageSelectorVC.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. This is not the correct code to add a subview that has its own controller. You should use custom container calls, e.g.:

   ```
   -(void)setUpImageSelectorView{
       ImageSelectorViewViewController *imageSelectorVC = [[ImageSelectorViewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageSelectorViewViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self addChildViewController:imageSelectorVC];
       imageSelectorVC.delegate = self;
       imageSelectorVC.view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
       imageSelectorVC.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
       imageSelectorVC.imageView.image = img;
       [self.view addSubview:imageSelectorVC.view];
       // you probably should set the `frame` of this view, too
       [imageSelectorVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
   }
   ```

   Note the `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController` calls.

   When you go to remove it, first call `[imageSelectorVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil]` and when when you're done removing everything, call `[self removeChildViewController: imageSelectorVC]`.

   See [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.* For a discussion of why all of this is so important (namely, keeping your view hierarchy synchronized with your view controller hierarchy) see WWDC 2011 video [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).
2. If you run the app through the debugger and pause the execution (hit the pause button, not the stop button), you can confirm the layout of the views by typing

   ```
   (lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
   <UIWindow: 0x7fd91b542420; frame = (0 0; 375 667); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd91b543000>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fd91b5412d0>>
      | <UIView: 0x7fd91b5442d0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd91b5435c0>>
      |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fd91b5445e0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd91b537030>>
      |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fd91b544f40; frame = (0 667; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd91b543850>>
      |    | <UIButton: 0x7fd91b446d50; frame = (5 285; 70 30); opaque = NO; tag = 12221; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd91b4d8fb0>>
      |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fd91b57aa20; frame = (0 0; 70 30); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd91b53b6f0>>
      |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fd91b51c040; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd91b539670>>
   ```

   Sometimes views are there, but you won't see it if their width/height is zero (especially if you are clipping to the bounds).

Comment: I found that the adding the line ``[self addChildViewController:imageSelectorVC]`` fixed the problem. The call I used to remove the child view controller was ``[ImageSelectorViewController.view removeFromSuperview];``

Comment: Sure, but after to remove the view, you presumably should `removeChildViewController`, too (and the `willMoveToParentViewController:nil`)